# Are there any laws that govern the use of code that lacks a license?

Tags: licensing

I recently found some use of code in some program I was asked to complete. The code it was taken from didn't have a license. This made me think there should be some rules/laws that govern that kind of work. I didn't know what they could be, hence this question.

For my own personal toys I always at least make sure to leave a comment detailing where something came from. At minimum It seems like the decent thing to do.

Comment: If it's that important, ask a lawyer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is absolutely not public domain in most countries; see the [Berne convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berne_convention) for copyright.

Study it, throw it away and rewrite it from scratch if you want to be safe - or at least, safe *r*. This way you only have to worry about software patents.

IANAL, etc.

Comment: This is what I was wondering. I figured there was something on the matter, I just didn't know what.

Answer (score 7):

Many countries have an implicit copyright, so no, it is not in the public domain.

Comment: "Many" being all Berne convention countries.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berne_Convention_for_the_Protection_of_Literary_and_Artistic_Works

Comment: I have had programmers at large companies write me to make sure it's ok to use some random snippet of code on my blog (and to give permission in writing).  I guess it's because the company has a policy.  I always give it because my intention was to share it (I probably should go mark everything as public domain, but it's too much of a pain).

Comment: @wnoise, yes thanks for finding this.

Comment: Normally not every piece of work can get a copyright, but the criteria vary from country to country, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threshold_of_originality

Answer (score 0):

How do you know that the code was taken? Is it in the comments? If so, you probably should get it in writing from the author. A lack of a license doesn’t mean you *can* use it, but depending on the country you (and the author) are in, it may be legal. Regardless of the country, the original author’s blessing will go a long way.